# Matplotlib iterate plots without if statements - Python3

Tags: python, matplotlib, iteration

On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation there is a graph shown...

[image: Plots of quadratic function]

It shows the quadratic y = ax2 + bx + c, varying each coefficient separately while the other coefficients are fixed (at values a = 1, b = 0, c = 0)

As a learning experience I decided to replicate these plots in Matplotlib as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

#Plot the quadratic function y = ax2 + bx + c
#Varying each coefficient [a, b, c] separately while the other coefficients are fixed (at values a = 1, b = 0, c = 0)

#Iterate these 5 coeficients and plot each line
coefs = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]

#set up the plot and 3 subplots (to show the effect of varying each coefficient)
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True, figsize=(18, 6))

#some x values to plot
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 30)

for idx, val in enumerate([ax1, ax2, ax3]):

    for i, v in enumerate(coefs):        
        a, b, c = 1, 0, 0

        if idx == 0:
            a = v
        elif idx == 1:
            b = v
        else:
            c = v

        y = a * (x**2) + (b * x) + c

        val.plot(x, y, label="Coeficient is " + str(coefs[i]))

        val.axhline(y=0, color='k')
        val.axvline(x=0, color='k')    
        val.grid()
        val.legend(loc='lower center')

plt.show()
```

It works fine...

[image: My plot]

but I am new to programming and I have an uneasy feeling that using if statements isn't optimal. It feels like I should be iterating over something rather than using ifs.

What other ways could I iterate over the coefficients a, b & c to produce the 3 different subplots?

Comment: you can think about what you would do if you have 100 coefficients.

Comment: and `coefs[i]` is `v` in your code. and `i` is not used elsewhere

Comment: But for working code I think you should post on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is a lot better than most "new programmers" I see here. This is probably close to how I would do it. I agree that this is more suited to code review.

Comment: @appleapple That's a violation of [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_ned_it)

Comment: @FHTMitchell which one? I don't quite get it.

Comment: @appleapple Thinking about what if we had 100 coefficients. This is thinking ahead when we don't need to. We only have 3 coefficients right now, and this code is more than suitable at handling that.

Comment: @FHTMitchell Yes I agree. I just reply to OP for *how to not use if*, though.

Comment: Thank you I have posted in code review. Should I delete this question now? I am not familiar with the protocol yet